# call child static function from parent?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose we have the following:

```
class Parent {
public:
     virtual void run() {
         for (int i = 0 ; i < bar.size() ; ++it)
              cout << i << "\n" ;
     };
protected:
     static vector<int> foo() {return vector r({1,2,3,4,5});};
     static vector<int> bar;
}
vector<int> Parent::bar = Parent::foo();
```

Now if I create a child class whose run function would be called externally, how can I redefine the foo function to return something else while still using the parent run function?

Edit: Sorry let me add some more information. Suppose the virtual function run() is a lot of code, all of which is essentially the same. The only difference in the parent and child classes is what values I want specified in the vector bar, so it would seem to be a little wasteful to redefine the virtual function in the child class. However, if you redefine Child::bar, and call Child::run(), the Parent::bar is used since it's defined in the parent class. Is there some way to have the line "vector Parent::bar = Parent::foo();" know in the Child class to use "Child::foo();"?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. You mean you want `Child::foo()` to return `false`?

Comment: edited the question with more information, hopefully it will help

Comment: Could you explain why `bar` need to be static? Subclassing to override static values seems a bit odd.

Comment: I'm not subclassing strictly for the bar variable, there are many other things inherited that I'm not including in this example. I suppose I don't need to make it static, then I can make it virtual, though it'd be the same value for any instance.

Answer (score 1):

As usual. Override base virtual function in derived class.

```
class Parent {
public:
     virtual bool run() {return bar;};
     static bool foo() {return true;};
     static bool bar;
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
   static bool foo() { return false;};
};
```

You can then still use base version applying `Base::` scope resolution:

```
int main() {

    bool bc = Child::foo();
    bool bp = Parent::foo();

    std::cout << bc << bp;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/TdaNQ5

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've edited the problem with more information - the point is I don't want to rewrite the base virtual function, since it's a lot of code, but calling the run function would then result in the base foo being used.

Comment: what do you mean by "calling the run function would then result in the base foo being used"?

Comment: If I called Child::run(), it would use Parent::bar which was defined by Parent::foo()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you exactly want here. However, you can override the static function like this,

```
class Child: public Parent
{
public:
   static bool foo() {return false;};
};
```

Comment: I've added more information in the question, hopefully it would help

Answer (score 0):

You really don't say much about your problem, therefore it is hard to distinguish what you need from what is potentially an XY problem.

One potential problem with your architecture is that you have a `Parent` and a `Child` classes that *share* a static variable `bar` yet you seem to initialize them differently for `Parent` and `Child` classes. However, there is only one `bar` that is shared both by Parent and `Child` objects, independently of who wrote to it last.

So, what do you expect when both a `Parent` and a `Child` objects are used simultaneously? The answer you look for depends on your answer on that one. In particular, if your answer is 'it is not designed to have `Parent` and `Child` objects operate simultaneously', then both classes should definitely not share a static variable.